# Plugin and themes are adding the same stylesheets

Tags: themes, css, wp-enqueue-style

> /vendors/font-awesome/font-awesome.min.css? ver=2.9.10
>
> /yith-woocommerce-wishlist/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css? ver=4.7.0
>
> /theme/css/font-awesome.min.css

**this csss are from different plugins and main theme.

and error is :

The following resources have identical contents, but are served from different URLs. Serve these resources from a consistent URL to save 2 request(s) and 60.5KiB.**

how can i combine them as one?

autoptimize wp plugin is not compatible with my website.

https://www.tarhdokan.com/

Answer (score 2):

You can use [wp_dequeue_style()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_style) to remove CSS a plugin is adding.

You can use it to dequeue the 2 stylesheets coming from your plugin and just keep the one in your theme.

However, they appear to be different versions of Font Awesome so you may run into some issues there, I'm not sure I don't use Font Awesome.

Here is an example of `wp_dequeue_style()` which you can edit and add to your theme's functions.php.

```
function wpse_remove_styles() {
   wp_dequeue_style('dokan-fontawesome');
}
add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'wpse_remove_styles', 100 );
```

Note: You will need the handle for the stylesheet, which you can usually get by viewing the source, finding the stylesheet ID and removing -css.  For example, in your case...

`<link rel='stylesheet' id='dokan-fontawesome-css'  href='.../vendors/font-awesome/font-awesome.min.css?ver=2.9.10' type='text/css' media='all' />`

The handle should be `dokan-fontawesome`.